# set default root working directory on php using apache server

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

How to I set php on apache for that the default working directory is `/var/www/html/`. The problem is that if I try to load a resource located in the root directory of the server from a script located in the same directory, I need to pass `/var/www/html/some_resource` instead of `/ some_resource`.

I tried:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
```

on apache `httpd.conf`.

Comment: That should work, can you edit your question to show us how it looks?

Comment: what's your DocumentRoot set to? there's no way a properly configured webserver would use `/var/wwww/html` as part of the public-facing urls. that'd mean your web document root is also the root of the filesystem, which is a ludicrously insanely bad security problem.

Comment: Add `DocumentRoot /mnt/www/public` before `<Directory "/var/www/html/">`

Comment: My configuration file looks like this :
    `<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin ioarbelaezr@unal.edu.co
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory></VirtualHost>`

Comment: If you want it relative to the working directory, use "some_resource" or "./some_resource" rather than "/some_resource" which attempts to use an absolute path.